# Custom Content Type with No Page View

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I am trying to define a custom content type, more exactly I want to create some controls in a content type for a slider that I will show on the home page custom template.

What I would like to know if it's possible to make the content type to don't have a view (a actual page where it would show up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When register your CPT, to make the content type don't have a view, you cant set `publicly_queryable` to `false`. According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), "If you set this to FALSE, you will find that you cannot preview/see your custom post (return 404)."